# 2D Graphics and image won't show correctly

Tags: java

First of all, I have two class' **GameGUI** and **paintCircle**

In **paintCircle** I'm drawing my circle on top of my JPanel image from ***GameGUI***, but with the standard grey-ish background

- I only want the circle to show, what am I missing? I've been through all the different settings without any luck.

The same goes for when I've tried to put in a new image of a triangle (.PNG-file), how do I only make the triangle visible or even change its size?

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        Ellipse2D.Double e = new Ellipse2D.Double(200,200,200,200);
        g2d.setColor(Color.red);
        g2d.fill(e);
        }
```

Comment: Generally, don't use multiple components for this.  Use a single rendering surface (ie `JPanel`).  Render the image and then render any graphics you want over it

Comment: Could you explain why not to use multiple components?
- Regarding your answer, it is what I'm doing without success.

Comment: Because you have problems like the one you have now, it's also a "heavy" load, as apposed to rendering primitive graphics. If you need something a little more complex or layered, consider devising a "paintable" concept which can take a reference of `Graphics2D` and perform it's painting operations.  Remember, components also have a concept of position and size, and painting it done at the components position offset (0x0 is the components top/left position)

Comment: Okay, thank you I will have that in mind.
It worked perfectly, TY. Do you know of any setting where I can change the size of an image/drawing (PNG-file).

Comment: [Java: maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928)

Comment: That is way to complicated for me at this point, but thank you.